# Задержка перед сменой слайда в Swiper Slider

Tags: javascript, slider, слайдер, swiper

Имеется Swiper slider.
После клика по кнопке Next или свайпа необходимо добавить анимацию перед сменой слайда.
Т.е. нажал кнопку и только через секунду-две слайд меняется

Пробовал поиграться со slideChangeTransitionStart и TransitionStart, но ничего не выходит

```
promoSlider.on('slideChangeTransitionStart', function() {
          promoSlider.slideNext(2000, false);

        })
```

2 вариант

```
function changeSlide() {
         promoSlider.slideNext();
        }
        promoSlider.on('sliderMove', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            setTimeout(changeSlide, 2000);
        });
```